# Change FS definition past the header of a CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, awk

I got this kind of CSV file:

```
name,x-extension,value,extra 
"Roger","9890","",""
"Nicole","9811","president, ceo",""
...
```

Now, I want the find the maximum size of each field in the file. So I used this awk script:

Updated script:

```
NR==1 {
    gsub(/\r/,"",$0) #remove linefeed from last field name
    for (n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
        colname[n]=$n;
        maxlen[n]=-1;
    }
    nbrField = NF; # will get bump +2 by the new FS
    FS="\",\"|^\"|\"$";
}

NR>1 {
    for (n = 2; n <= nbrField+1; n++) {
        if (length($n)>maxlen[n-1]) {
            maxlen[n-1]=length($n);
        }
    }
}

END {
    for(i = 1; i <= nbrField; i++) {
        printf "%s : %s\n", colname[i], maxlen[i]
    }
}
```

The problem a got is I need to change the field separator AFTER reading the first line because as you can see, the header don't use double quote for field delimiter and there is coma INSIDE some field.

I tried to play with this -F option on my awk command line but I can't find the right combination of regex to do the trick..

```
> awk -F'", "|^"|"$' -f myprog mydata  ==>(don't work)
```

Help! :-)

Comment: Can't you assign to `FS` in the `NR==1` block?

Comment: export data with `|` or tab chars and avoid a whole class of problems? Good luck.

Comment: Cannot change the export data, it's outside our organisation :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `FS` in the block that processes the first line:

```
NR==1 {
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
       colname[n]=$n
    }
    FS="\",\"|^\"|\"$"
}
```

Comment: I'm tried it but I need to work my regex because the capture of the field are out of sync with the name of my fields

Comment: The field numbers will start at `2` and end at `NF-1`, because there's an empty field before the quote at the beginning of the line and after the quote at the end. `FS` isn't really designed to work with containers like quotes.

Comment: your were right for the first part (2), but the end is NF+1

Comment: Updated script above!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a real CSV parser for CSV data. For example, Perl:

```
perl -MText::CSV -MList::Util=max -nE '
    BEGIN {$csv = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1})}
    $csv->parse($_);
    @row = $csv->fields();
    if ($. == 1) {
        @h = @row; $n = $#row;
    }
    else {
        $max{$h[$_]} = max($max{$h[$_]}, length $row[$_]) for (0..$n)
    }
    END {
        while (($k,$v) = each %max) {say join ":", $k, $v}
    }
' << DATA
name,x-extension,value,extra
"Roger","9890","",""
"Nicole","9811","president, ceo",""
DATA
```

```
value:14
name:6
extra:0
x-extension:4
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but prefer working with awk for this kind of job! :-)